# Remove some photos (or videos) from iPhoto without deleting from Flickr

Tags: photos.app, flickr

I have a very large iPhoto library with photos and videos shared to Flickr using the built-in iPhoto/Flickr integration. I've run into problems with the size of my iPhoto library (>100GB) so I'm splitting it in two to help manage the space.

I understand that iPhoto syncs photos with Flickr rather than exports them, so if I remove a photo from my iPhoto library, it will delete it from Flickr. While historically, I've enjoyed this sync approach, with splitting up my iPhoto library it is problematic.

**What is the best way to remove photos from iPhoto that have been published to Flickr (or Facebook for that matter) without deleting them from Flickr?**

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer here:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2432?locale=en_US

Very simple actually, just remove the Facebook and Flickr accounts in preferences and then delete away!